# I am trying to write some data into Excel file using Cypress tool but getting error

Tags: excel, cypress

I am trying to write some data into Excel file using Cypress tool but getting error.
trying to use 'exceljs' `const Excel = require('exceljs')` but getting error "Can't resolve 'exceljs' in 'D:\Branches\3006_LatestMaster"

using code

```js
var Excel = require('exceljs'); 
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook(); 
var filePath = "D:\\Myspectra\\test.xlsx" 
function check() { 
  console.log('saky') 
  workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(()=> { 
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1'); 
    console.log(worksheet.getCell('D3').value) //= "Saky" 
    //Change the cell number here return 
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filePath) 
    //Change file name here or give file path 
  }).catch((err)=>{ 
    console.log("error",err) 
  }); 
} 
check();
```

Comment: using code var Excel = require('exceljs');
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
var filePath = "D:\\Myspectra\\test.xlsx"
 
function check() {
    console.log('saky')
     workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(()=> {
            var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
            console.log(worksheet.getCell('D3').value) //= "Saky" //Change the cell number here
 
            return workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filePath) //Change file name here or give file path
 
        }).catch((err)=>{
             console.log("error",err)
        });
    
}
 
check();

Comment: Did you install exceljs - `npm i -D exceljs` or `yarn add -D exceljs`?